# JavaFX: Fit child elements to HBox width

Tags: javafx, width, hbox

Is it possible to manage child elements in a HBox, so that the sum of the widths of all child elements is equal to the width of the HBox?

So that elements fill the HBox and no space is left.

The height of the child elements is by default the height of the HBox, so how about the width? I don't want to calculate the width in my program. It would be better if the layout does this automatically, so that no calculation is needed.

Comment: HBox lays out its children horizontally. It does not make sense to make every child the same width as the HBox.

Comment: No, not the same width as the hbox, the width summary of all childs should be equal to the hbox width. So that the hbox is filled fully with the childs and no space is left.

Comment: Should the children have equal width?

Comment: yes, all the same width

Comment: @AKR just dont specify the HBox's width and it will occupy the width of all the children !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It depends what kind of children does the `HBox` contain. Some of the children may not be resizable nodes. However, generally speaking, you can use `HBox.setHgrow()` method and set the same `Priority` for all children of hbox. The explanation is in its javadoc:

> Sets the horizontal grow priority for the child when contained by an
>   hbox. If set, the hbox will use the priority to allocate additional
>   space if the hbox is resized larger than it's preferred width. If
>   multiple hbox children have the **same** horizontal grow **priority**, then
>   the extra space will be **split** evening **between them**. If no horizontal
>   grow priority is set on a child, the hbox will never allocate it
>   additional horizontal space if available. Setting the value to null
>   will remove the constraint.

Additionally, if you are trying to obtain a grid-like layout then try out other layout options, for instance `TilePane` or `FlowPane` and maybe `GridPane`.

Comment: setHgrow has solved the problem. Other layouts like gridpane was no good option for me, because the child nodes in the hbox (flowpanes) should be resizable. With gridpane i had lots of trouble with the resizing of the child nodes.

Answer (score 16):

The simple code for your answer would be this:

```
Button button1 = new Button("Save");
Button button2 = new Button("Delete");
HBox.setHgrow(button1, Priority.ALWAYS);
HBox.setHgrow(button2, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

It's recommended to use HBox class rather than name of HBox pane.

Answer (score 9):

In `FXML`:

```
<HBox>
   <Label HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" maxWidth="Infinity">
       TEST
   </Label>
</HBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @bdshahab's answer, since HBox will try to resize their children to their preferred widths, they will only fill the box if their combined preferred widths are wider than the HBox width.

So it may be necessary to do something like:

```
Button button1 = new Button("Save");
Button button2 = new Button("Delete");
HBox.setHgrow(button1, Priority.ALWAYS);
HBox.setHgrow(button2, Priority.ALWAYS);
button1.setPrefWidth(100000);
button2.setPrefWidth(100000);
```